# Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance error?

Tags: laravel

I trying to delete something in my database.

following error occur:

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. (View:
>   G:\Laravel\Projects\laravelApp1\resources\views\event.blade.php)

[image]

this is my route code:

```
Route::get('/event',function(){
    $a=App\event::all();
    return view('event')->with('event',$a);
});

Route::post('/eventSave', 'eventController@eventSave');

Route::get('/event/delete/{id}',[
        'uses'=>'eventController@eventDelete',
        'as'=>'event.delete'
]);
```

this is my event.blade.php:

```
@foreach($event as $eventData)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$eventData->eventName}}</td>
      <td>{{$eventData->reason}}</td>
      <td>{{$eventData->region}}</td>
      <td>{{$eventData->budget}}</td>
      <td>{{$eventData->startDate}}</td>
      <td>{{$eventData->startTime}}</td>
      <td>{{$eventData->endTime}}</td>
      <td><a href="{{route('event.delete',['id' => $event->id]) }}" class="btn.btn-default">X</button></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

this is my eventController.php:

```
public function eventDelete($id){
    //dd($id);
    $a=event::find($id);
    $a->delete();
}
```

plz..help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In yor foreach on `event.blade.php` you tried to access `$event`, that is a collection, what you want is `$eventData`.

```
<td><a href="{{route('event.delete',['id' => $eventData->id]) }}" class="btn.btn-default">X</button></td>
```